# easiest way to aggregate values over multiple columns?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table that looks like this:

| classification | animal1 | animal2 | animal3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mammal | dog | cat |  |
| bird | parrot | owl |  |
| mammal | cat | zebra | lion |
| fish | goldfish | tuna |  |
| bird | ostrich | parrot | chicken |

My goal is to make a summary of each animal based on their classification, i.e. basically just to get a count of each animal and their corresponding classification such that:

| classification | animal   | count    |
| --------       | -------- | -------- |
| mammal         | dog      | 1        |
| mammal         | cat      | 2        |
| mammal         | zebra    | 1        |
| mammal         | lion     | 1        |
| bird           | parrot   | 2        |
| bird           | owl      | 1        |
...

The way I did this (and this might be a very beginner solution, I'm afraid I'm making it more complicated than it should be) is by doing the following:

| classification | animal | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mammal | dog | 1 |
| mammal | cat | 2 |
| mammal | zebra | 1 |
| mammal | lion | 1 |
| bird | parrot | 2 |
| bird | owl | 1 |

First, I work in the second column. I get the unique list of all animals using array formula, unique, and flatten at the same time like:

=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(B2:D)))

This gives me a list of all the animals from columns B to D.

Then, to get the value in the first column, I add a column in the original raw file that concatenates the animals in the 3 columns:

| classification | animal1 | animal2 | animal3 | concat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mammal | dog | cat |  | dog, cat |
| bird | parrot | owl |  | parrot, owl |
| mammal | cat | zebra | lion | cat, zebra, lion |
| fish | goldfish | tuna |  | goldfish, tuna |
| bird | ostrich | parrot | chicken | ostrich, parrot, chicken |

Then I use index match to get the classification

From there, I just use a COUNTIF on the third column to count the instances of each animal in the columns B:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how you solved the problem. I personally try to avoid helper columns, especially for simple problems so here's how I would do it.

```
=SORT(LET(cc,TOCOL(A2:A&"ζ"&B2:D),QUERY(UNIQUE({SPLIT(cc,"ζ"),COUNTIF(cc,cc)}),"WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL")),1,0)
```

First we [unpivot the table](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/unpivot-in-google-sheets/), then we run a `COUNTIF` and finally we remove the duplicate and blank rows and sort the result.

Btw, `UNIQUE(FLATTEN(B2:D))` is not an array formula so you don't need an `ARRAYFORMULA` wrapper around it. Also, we have [`TOCOL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) now, which is a better version of `FLATTEN`, I recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=index(let(Σ,tocol(if(len(B2:D),A2:A&"|"&B2:D,),1),
           sort({split(unique(Σ),"|"),countif(Σ,unique(Σ))})))
```

[image]